# New hybrid drive (Seagate Desktop SHDD) suddenly is slowing down.

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, performance, disk-activity

I have a two months old 2TB Seagate Desktop SSHD.

I’m running this SSHD as a secondary drive (have an SSD running as boot), being a "backup" drive.

I've created two partitions with it:

- one with 1.5TB
- one with 300GB'ish

Suddently whenever requesting anything from that drive, the response time is VERY slow. At a point it was slow and next day alright again, however the last 4-5 days it has been consistantly slow.

**I experience the following:**

- When clicking through folders and (usually) reaching some 2-3 inner folder index, the SSDH stops up and VERY slowly loads (with progress bar) before the folder renders
- Writing to a file (like .txt, .php, .js /whatever) *saving work - takes 3-4 secs everytime saving
- I have noticed that the drive would very often say some "tick" noises, like it was "thinking", even when nothing really would be happening on the computer.
- Under "Joblist > Disc profiling - I don't see anything unusual pingin' out here (without knowing much about processes)

**I have tried the following:**

- Right click on the drive and run for the disc for errors > nothing found
- Under "Storage"/"Disk Management" under status it says "E: + D: > Status: Ok, primary partion" (whereas the C: says "Boot, Chrashdump, Primary partion")

Any suggestions on further "debugging" or things I could check or do before considering sending it back to the supplier?

Comment: any update? Have you tried my tip to prevent HDD sleep?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the slow speeds are indicators of a failing drive, so it was a good decision to run chkdsk on it to see what the results will be. However, in order to be sure I'd suggest to run another test but this time instead of the OS tool I will recommend to check in the official manufacturer website if a diagnostic tool is available to use and run a test with it  since this software will be tuned to the firmware of the drive.

Before doing so don't forget to backup your most important data in order to prevent any potential data loss.

Hope this helps and let us know how it went.

Comment: "chkdsk.exe /f /r" is a 5 stages and slow lengthy operation. My 1TB ST1000LX015-1U7172 ran for about 2 hours to complete. Recommend to run it after office hour or before going to bed.

Answer (score 1):

You should [prevent the 2nd HDD to sleep](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-hard-drive-going-sleep-windows):

> To prevent the Hard Disk from going to sleep, click on the Battery /
>   Power icon in the taskbar and select More Power options. In the
>   Control Panel windows which opens, select Change Plan settings for
>   your current Power Plan. In the next window, select Change advanced
>   power settings.
>
> In the Power Options box that opens, click the + sign next to the Hard
>   Disk option. Here you will see the required settings under Turn off
>   hard disk after heading. Change the value to 0.

[image]

This should improve the response time of the second HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Unusual sounds and intermittent slow response usually indicates a failing drive. Get your data copied to another drive and pull the misbehaving hard drive out of service.

Comment: My SSHD ST1000LX015-1U7172 always has sound. I experienced once unusual intermittent slow response and hanging behavior on my notebook. It was due to hard disk over heating. I follow the tips in this page to reduce hard disk activities.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn off the SSHD write caching policy

[image]

Comment: @semiL - All improvements should be in the form of an edit to your answer instead of a comment in the future.  While I improved the answer for you, the screenshot is not in English, and there is an expected answer will be written in English (or a proper English translation is provided).  Which is one of the reasons screenshot only answers are not encourage.

Comment: For unknown reason, maybe after my notebook woke up from sleep mode, I could feel the notebook harddisk SSHD ST1000LX015-1U7172 heated up from the notebook casing. The notebook response was lagging and hanging. I follow this step, Device Manager > Disk drive >  ST1000LX015-1U7172 > (right click Properties) > Policies. And also follow the tips https://whatsabyte.com/windows/fix-100-disk-usage-windows-10/ to reduce hard disk activities.